# Which is the correct stylus weight for the stylus provided with Roadstar TTL-8743DJ?

Tags: turntable

I’ve searched and searched, and even written the manufacturer, but to no avail. Even [the manual](https://www.google.no/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://files.elv.com/service/manuals_hw/71133_TTL-8743UDJ_UM.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjHyPeb4bjSAhWHjywKHb7GAjQQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNFFi7RXIhJ8YlrMBykJFr99lgeF9A&sig2=zDQhlr3W6oGCGFC24RuXoA) provides no insight, only saying that

> After adjusting the horizontal zero (0) balance, turn the balanced counterweight counter-clockwise to get the proper stylus pressure as the cartridge manufacturer's recommendation when it meets center lounge of the tone arm rear shaft.

The stylus is the standard provided with the turntable (to the best of my knowledge); even though it’s old, I’d still like to use it correctly, so as to not damage my records. If anyone can find the missing information, I would appreciate it greatly, as I plan to give the player to a friend of mine.

Comment: From what I know, the weight is adjusted with experience. The stylus has to slightly touch the record without putting too much pressure on it. Too much weigh, and you will dig your record. Not enough weight and the stylus will jump on light old record scratches. You can find [tutorials](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=adjust+turntable+weight) on how to adjust the weight.

Comment: Which is the method I've used. However, this is a more touch-and-feel method, working, but imprecise at best. The actual correct weight is hopefully within the range of what one finds, though most likely deviating too much from the correct weight.

Comment: As far as I know, the "correct" weight depends on the record. Some records will require to increase the weight a little, otherwise the stylus will jump... so I'm not sure there is a constant and defined value. Good luck to you ;-)